# Java java.lang.ClassCastException: some.package.SomeClass cannot be cast to some.package.SomeClass

Tags: java, wsdl

I am calling a soap web service that has a structure that we generate from a wsdl, using wsdl2java. one of the packages/class is some.package.SomeClass.  Once we get the result of that service in some.package.SomeClass, we call a jar, that has some.package.SomeClass as input to it.  They truly are the same class, so how can I easily overcome this issue.  I know I could change the input of the jar to a different package/object name, but it is truly the object that is also being generated from the wsdl, so I dont want to change it.  How can I overcome this error in such a way so the class generated from the wsdl, and the input to the jar can be the same package and class name?

Any help would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are probably seeing the classes loaded by different class loaders, which are already different classes even if they have the same full qualified name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the generated class if you have it packed in a jar that is given to you .
just drop the thing that you have generated , and use the classes from the jar...

Comment: I excluded the from the wsdl from the cxf-codegen-plugin/wsdl2java and now the classes are not getting generated, I imported the jar, but now for some strange reason java does not include the classes/packages from the jar.  Any ideas why?

Comment: what else did you change along with that exclusion ?

Comment: Nothing, I simply told cxf-codegen-plugin to exclude 1 specific class from being generated.  When I try to compile my code it now complains that the class cannot be found.  However I can see it there in the jar within my maven dependencies.  Seems like the classloader still thinks that the wsdl2java generated classes are different than the ones from the jar even though they have the exact same package and classname becuase they are the same class.